# Join 2 PairRDDs without shuffling

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have 2 PairRDDs: rddA that is of huge size and rddB that is much smaller. I need to join them by key, so that I could further iterate over pairs of elements of those PairRDDs corresponding to the same key. PairRDD#join method seems to be exactly what I need, but I see that it involves shuffling, thus resulting in writing huge data volumes to HDFS and frequent out-of-memory errors. Is there any way to avoid the shuffling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce shuffling data must be colocated on the same cluster nodes.

- Control the partitioning at data source level and/or using .partition operator
- If the small RDD can fit in memory of all workers, then using broadcast variable is the faster option

Some pointers which helped me:

- [Advanced Spark Training](https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/slides/advanced-spark-training.pdf) in particular around slide 12
- About joining with broadcast maps: [Advanced Spark Features](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/matei-zaharia-amp-camp-2012-advanced-spark.pdf) in particular slides 9-12

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll check if this help.

Comment: By the way, aren't RDD elements with the same keys located on the same cluster node by default?

Comment: For 1 RDD, it is true, but for 2 RDD it isn't and it is the reason of shuffling.